# Where to save the local DB created for iphone app?

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, cordova, icloud

I have developed a app that loads fully static content . I am storing data more than 4 mb of size. With out this content the app will not work. In my case where should i save the local database(documents folder or library folder).

My app got rejected since it was backed up for iCloud storage.

1) Where should i save the database? In Library folder or inside Documents folder?

2) Since apple rejected my app i believe that I should not backup the database for iCloud. Please correct me if i was wrong.

3) In my app i am also taking screen shot and saving in document directory to attach it in mail. Whether can i save the screen shot in document directory or should i save it the caches folder? Please update.

Please guide me the right way to implement DB .

Thanks

Comment: I have created app with database, and stored it in document directory. That application was accepted by apple. So document directory is good option

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code in your application before saving database to your document directory..

```
-(BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];

    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);

//  NSLog(@"Attributs : %d and Path : %@",result,URL);
    if (result != 0) { 

        NSLog(@"File Backup Attribute setting error");

    }

    return result == 0;
}
```