# Where should I save .db file in my IOS app?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I use SQLite Database in my project. I wonder where should I save my .db file after its creation in order to suit Apple requirements? I mean in what directory (.DocumentsDirectory or .Caches)?

Comment: you should definitely store your SQLite Database in  Documents Directory.

Comment: this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840318/should-i-write-sqlite-database-file-to-documents-directory-or-library-caches